# Install TP-link TL-WN725N USB wifi driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have a USB wifi adaper tp-link model TL-WN725N. It was working fine but suddenly today it's saying that "No wifi adapters found". So I tried installing a driver from [this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn725n/v3/) page. But the installation failed. `make all` command wasn't compiling then I checked the website again. In the website it says, `Operating System: Linux (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.19.3)`. But my kernal is `5.11.0-25-generic`. And the USB device finds all the wifi that are available. But it can't connect to them. What can I do now?

This is the error that I am getting:

```
$HOME/Documents/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:261:8: error: ‘_timer’ {aka ‘struct timer_list’} has no member named ‘data’
  261 |  ptimer->data = (unsigned long)cntx;
      |        ^~
$HOME/Documents/Driver/include/osdep_service_linux.h:262:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘_init_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  262 |  init_timer(ptimer);
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~
      |  _init_timer
```

Some other useful command outputs:

```
➜ ifconfig
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 10:7b:44:32:b5:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3866  bytes 321595 (321.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3866  bytes 321595 (321.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx7cc2c61b3890: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::f871:26fc:9f55:13ed  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7c:c2:c6:1b:38:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 348 (348.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 3460 (3.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
➜ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

More outputs:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 07 Aug 2021 05:18 +06 +0600

Booted last: 07 Aug 2021 00:00 +06 +0600

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.11.0-25-generic #27~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 13 17:41:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0bda:b721 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a01 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 035: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

EFI variables are not supported on this system

##### lsmod #############################

r8188eu               421888  0
lib80211               16384  1 r8188eu
cfg80211              888832  1 r8188eu
asus_nb_wmi            32768  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
asus_wmi               36864  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon
video                  49152  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
14: wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  unassociated  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         695       1  0 Aug06 ?        00:00:29 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8188eu
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.11.0-25-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   353f4586-0b86-4c1f-86aa-40c066ce5b31 | Redmi

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.11.0-25-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID       BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 
Redmi      <MAC 'Redmi' [AC2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  44 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      no             
Free wifi  <MAC 'Free wifi' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  44 Mbit/s  23      ▂___  WPA2      no             

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sir MMR Hall - 4th Floor Root.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sir MMR Hall - 4th Floor Root | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sir MMR Hall - 4th Floor Root
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sir MMR Hall-Block 2.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sir MMR Hall-Block 2 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sir MMR Hall-Block 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Redmi.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Redmi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Redmi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR85.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR85 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=NETGEAR85
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Dhaka (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Free wifi' [AC1]>
                    ESSID:"Free wifi"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=23/100  
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Redmi' [AC2]>
                    ESSID:"Redmi"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:108 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=69/100  

##### module infos ######################

[r8188eu]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8188eu/r8188eu.ko
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
depends:        cfg80211,lib80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           r8188eu
vermagic:       5.11.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_cbw40_enable:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_fw_iol:FW IOL (int)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (1-9) (default 1) (int)
parm:           monitor_enable:Enable monitor interface (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-25-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[r8188eu]
debug: 1
if2name: wlan%d
ifname: wlan%d
monitor_enable: N
rtw_80211d: 0
rtw_ampdu_amsdu: 0
rtw_ampdu_enable: 1
rtw_antdiv_cfg: 2
rtw_antdiv_type: 0
rtw_cbw40_enable: 3
rtw_channel: 1
rtw_channel_plan: 66
rtw_enusbss: 0
rtw_fw_iol: 1
rtw_ht_enable: 1
rtw_hwpdn_mode: 2
rtw_initmac: (null)
rtw_ips_mode: 1
rtw_max_roaming_times: 2
rtw_mc2u_disable: 0
rtw_notch_filter: 0
rtw_power_mgnt: 1
rtw_rx_stbc: 1
rtw_smart_ps: 2
rtw_vcs_type: 1
rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
rtw_wifi_spec: 0
rtw_wmm_enable: 1

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[20207.578982] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[20207.617403] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[20207.617471] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
[22647.782046] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from wlan0 (repeated 2 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

And another thing is that it scans the available wifi. But it can't connect with them.

```
~ ➜ sudo dmesg | grep -e wlx -e r8188
[  124.081192] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  124.105802] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[  124.172294] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx7cc2c61b3890: renamed from wlan0
[  127.683225] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx7cc2c61b3890: link becomes ready
[  847.092120] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx7cc2c61b3890: renamed from wlan0
[  875.921812] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx7cc2c61b3890: link becomes ready
```

Comment: "wlx7cc2c61b3890" It looks like it's working to me. Does it scan and see networks? `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: Yes it scans. But it doesn't connect to the network. It says `Activation of network connection failed`. When I go the settings, I see no wifi adapters found.

Comment: Please provide the results of the wireless script from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I have added them.

Comment: What we do not see here is any attempt to connect and therefore any clue as to why it fails. Please click the Network Manager icon, select your network and attempt to connect. Supply the password if requested. Let it try and fail. Then run and post: `sudo dmesg | grep -e wlx -e r8188`

Comment: I don't know what happened but it's working now. But its strange. I didn't install any driver for it. And it took a very long time to connect to it. I don't know if this will be stable or not.

Comment: I have added those output. My USB isn't working again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are still unable to discover why the device, using the usual built-in kernel driver, doesn’t connect as expected. I notice, however, that the driver version here is newer than the built-in driver. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Let’s install it and see if it helps.

With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git 
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo -i
echo “blacklist r8188eu”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r r8188eu
exit
```

Remove and reinsert your USB wireless and tell us if there is any improvement.

At each newer kernel version update, after the requested restart, please do:

```
cd rtl8188eu
make clean
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

Please retain these instructions and the rtl8188eu directory for that time.

Comment: It works fine now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: tried this, (same device, same linux version), device now not working at all after reinserting it. journalctl shows  'not an MTP device'

Comment: after some searching it appears this could be a problem with having secure boot enabled?

Comment: @jimsmith Yes, indeed. Please disable Secure Boot.

Comment: this line inserts it with quotes into blacklist for me on ubuntu 20: echo “blacklist r8188eu”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf just use SIMPLE quotes here echo "blacklist r8188eu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf